# How to convert from Content Profile module back to core profile?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, user-profile

Reason being, I'd like to eventually upgrade to Drupal 7 and make use of what I hear is the new core "Profile 2".  I'm not fond of user data being stored as node data.  Is there a reasonable way to get any data from Content Profile and re-integrate that with the core profile?  Or would it entail something manual with the raw database using MySQL queries?

Comment: I didn't understand but Profile2 isn't core. 
The Old "Profile" module is deprecated, and included in Drupal 7 for legacy purposes only. By default, the module will be hidden from the UI unless you are upgrading a site that uses the Profile module to extend user profiles.<br/>
<br/>
"Profile 2" - Relationship to content profile<br/>
With the new concept of entities in Drupal 7, this module supersedes content profile as general solution. However for any situations where profiles as nodes might be preferable, content profile for Drupal 7 will build upon profile2.

Comment: Thanks.  I just have misread when doing research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an easy way AFAIK.

For these kind of things I've hand to do them by hand. With [content_profile_load](http://api.freestylesystems.co.uk/api/drupal/contributions--content_profile--content_profile.module/function/content_profile_load/6), [user_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_load/6), [profile_load_profile](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--profile--profile.module/function/profile_load_profile/6), and  [profile_save_profile](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--profile--profile.module/function/profile_save_profile/6) the code to convert it would be pretty short and easy.

I would stay with what you've got on Drupal 6 because migrating to Drupal 7 will likely be a pain no matter which system you're using.

Comment: Thanks.  I had been thinking in terms of SQL code, but modules would certainly make my life easier.  I'll examine these in more detail.  Who knows, perhaps something new will be available in the future at the point when we migrate to Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

Profile2 is a contributed module, not core, see http://drupal.org/project/profile2

So maybe it does or will support upgrading from content_profile directly. And even if not, it might not be more complicated to migrate back to profile.module and then to profile2.module.

Looking at http://drupal.org/node/1068446, there might be no official migration path from profile to profile2 yet.

Note that you don't necessarly need profile2 or even profile.module since D7 now has the ability to add Fields to users. That doesn't give you all the functionality of content_profile/profile2 though.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  This sounded promising: http://drupal.org/project/field_convert

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old thread, but incase it helps someone else out, I managed to migrate my content profile data to profile2 using the method [here](http://drupal.org/node/560324#comment-4906406).  I posted my own version of the code as a module to be edited in this [comment](http://drupal.org/node/560324#comment-5140826).  So if anything, check that thread out, specifically those two comments and hopefully you'll figure it out.